# Custom Emmet Snippets with Autocomplete

Tags: visual-studio-code, emmet

I created custom snippet in vscode for media query when typing css but it does not autocomplete when I type.

```
"snippets": {
      "q":"@include query(${1:}) { \n\t${2:}\n}"
}
```

Example: if I type

```
q
```

It shows exactly what I defined above.

If I type

```
q960
```

It should be:

```
@include query(960) {

}
```

But it does not work.

How can you help me to solve this? Thank you so much.

Comment: `q` __Enter__ `360` __Enter__

Comment: If you type just `q` what do you get again?